# 'Fields' variable does not show specified shapefile fields in Arcpy custom script

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, arcgis-10.7

I'm creating a script in ArcMap (ArcGIS 10.7.1).

I have created tool parameters to specify the workspace where the data is stored (Workspace), a shapefile displaying a boundary (Field boundary), a shapefile of soil points that will be interpolated (Soil points), and a few others (crop type, yield goal). Also to note, the soil points contain fields such as "Nitrogen", "Phosphorus", "Potassium", and a few others. I have verified their presence.

Below that, there is a field called "Nitrogen field" that should contain a list of all the fields that are found in the soil points shapefile, but they are not there when I open up the drop-down box. When setting up the tool parameters, I selected this parameter as a 'fields' data type, but nothing is there. **How can I make these fields visible in the drop-down box?**

Here's a picture of the tool parameter box to provide a better visual:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tool's 'Parameters' section, you need to select the field parameter ('Nitrogen field'), and then set its '**Obtained From**' setting to be the feature class parameter from which the list of fields should be derived ('Soil points').